# Serial port stops receiving data, sending any data temporarily fixes it

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running raspbian with two USB 2.0 to RS485 adapters attached. The OS maps these adapters to /dev/ttyUSB* addresses. Programs running on the RPi receive data from sensors using NMEA 0183 protocol. Previously, the open source program "kplex" was receiving data from both sensors, and was running indefinitely with no issue.

Recently, I changed my setup to read one of the serial ports, running at 4800 baud, directly with one of my own programs. I now have an issue where, after running for a "long" time, usually a day or so, the serial port stops receiving data from the sensor. The following are some of my diagnostics:

- Restarting my program, which reads data from the sensor, does not
  restart the receipt of the data.
- After stopping my program, other attempts to read data on the port, for example using "cat" or "screen" also show no data coming in.
- Rebooting the Raspberry Pi also does not resolve the issue.
- Adjusting the serial port configuration settings to match those used by kplex does not fix the issue
- The ONLY thing that I've found to reliably resolve the issue is to send any data to the serial port, for example `echo abc >/dev/ttyUSB1`
- After echoing data to the port, receipt of incoming data immediately resumes and continues for another day or so, after which it stops
- Using the program "stty" I've monitored the configuration options, which appear to persist on reboot.
- At one point, modifying some of these flags, I thought I had resolved the issue. Then, after a complete depower/repower of the RPi and sensor, it was working again for some time before the issue cropped up again.
- I have not identified a change to my code or port configuration which has reliably fixed the issue.
- The fact that it worked reliably using "kplex" makes me think it is a software configuration issue, but still not sure.
- The fact that sending data to the port fixes the issue makes me think it could be some hang up in the driver for the adapter, but again, it was working using "kplex."

What kind of problem could be causing these symptoms?

Comment: Are you using hardware handshaking?  It's possible its waiting for the correct handshake before moving on.

Comment: *"What kind of problem could be causing these symptoms?"* -- That is not how this site works.  We're not going to provide you with a checklist of possible causes.  Visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidelines.